# Get records with specific amount of years

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with Employees.

I need to get the employees that are working at the company for 5 years. Not 6, not 4. 5 Years.

The same for the ones who work there for 10 and for 15 years.

How can I do it?

That's what i currently have, but it's not working well. I have a employee which will be 5 years in 3 days and the query is selecting him anyways.

```
SELECT name, DATEDIFF(day, join_date, GETDATE())/365 as Years, join_date from employee
where
(
    DATEDIFF(day, join_date, GETDATE()) > 365*5 and 
    DATEDIFF(day, join_date, GETDATE()) < 365*6
)
OR
(
    DATEDIFF(day, join_date, GETDATE()) > 365*10 and 
    DATEDIFF(day, join_date, GETDATE()) < 365*11
)
OR
(
    DATEDIFF(day, join_date, GETDATE()) > 365*15 and 
    DATEDIFF(day, join_date, GETDATE()) < 365*16
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you use `dateadd()` rather than `datediff()` for this purpose:

```
where (join_date > dateadd(year, -6, getdate()) and join_date <= dateadd(year, -5, getdate())
      ) or
      (join_date > dateadd(year, -11, getdate()) and join_date <= dateadd(year, -10, getdate())
      ) or
      (join_date > dateadd(year, -15, getdate()) and join_date <= dateadd(year, -16, getdate())
      )
```

I would guess that your issue is that years don't have 365 days.  To a close approximation, they have 365.25 days.  But, adding intervals of years solves the problem of guessing how many days are in a given year.